# how to display lightbox after Video Play Finishes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, youtube, lightbox

I have a youtube video.

I want to show a lightbox when it stops playing. I need this to be done using javascript/jQuery or PHP. Ajax is also fine.

I looked for a solution but didn't find one that worked.

Comment: [What have your tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)? Could you post the code that does not work as expected and extend "exact"?

Comment: are you using youtube api to play the kewl video?

Comment: I don't know if he is, but I embedded it using Youtubes embedding codes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you can use youtube api then, something like this should work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
var player;
    function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '390',
          width: '640',
          videoId: 'YmHAAqOsBqA',
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
    }
    function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.playVideo();
    }
    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {        
        if(event.data === 0) {          
            //completed playing
            //open lightbox
            $('#yourElementId a').lightBox();
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

Did you mean something like this.

Hope it helps

Comment: Hi DanRedux would you mind to share your solution ? Thanks