# How to show something after embedded Youtube video

Tags: youtube, html

I'm building a website and am new to this. What I'm trying to do is get a youtube video embedded in the website and once the video ends it shows something else on the website, in my case a editText where the user can enter a word.

I don't care if the editText appears where the video was or just below it or anything along those lines..

I have found a couple of things such as the following:

[how to display lightbox after Video Play Finishes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10256636/how-to-display-lightbox-after-video-play-finishes)

but nothing happened

Also tried this code

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="public/javascripts/swfobject.js"></script> 
</head>

<body>

<div id="ytapiplayer">
    You will need Flash 8 or better to view this content.
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var params = { allowScriptAccess: "always" };
    var atts = { id: "ytplayer" };
    swfobject.embedSWF("http://www.youtube.com/v/OQSNhk5ICTI&enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=ytplayer", "ytapiplayer", "425", "365", "8", null, null, params, atts);

    function onYouTubePlayerReady(playerId) {
        alert('Player loaded');
        ytplayer = document.getElementById("ytplayer");
    }

    function play() { 
        alert(typeof ytplayer);
        if (ytplayer) { 
            alert(ytplayer.playVideo); 
            ytplayer.playVideo(); 
        } 
    }
</script>



 <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="play();">Play</a>

 </body>
 </html>
```

but I don't see a video appearing. I get a message saying 'undefined' if I click on Play

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach from your link ought to work. The [YouTube Player API Reference](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Getting_Started) does something similar, registering an `onStateChange` function. When the video ends that function should be passed `0`.

You might try positioning an element over the video but you have to tell flash to stick to it's z-level to do this. You can add `wmode: "opaque"` to the `playerVars` variable. This should allow you to place an element on top.

Edit - try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="ytapiplayer"></div>
    <script>
      var tag = document.createElement('script');
      tag.src = "//www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

      var player;
      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('ytapiplayer', {
          height: '390',
          width: '640',
          videoId: 'OQSNhk5ICTI',
          events: {
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
      }

      function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        if (event.data == 0) {
          alert("Finished!");
        }
      }

    </script>
    <p>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="player.playVideo(); return false;">Play</a>
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, however, the video never loads in the first place... I'll edit the question to clarify that..